# Regex for differentiating between phone number and year

Tags: python, regex

My regex matches a year range in the string when I only want to match phone numbers.

Here is an example test string:

```
Call on tel: (425) 882-8080 or 852-9876 and it does not 
necessarily reflect the views of Microsoft Corp from 1986-1989.
```

Here the matched strings are:

```
(425) 882-8080
852-9876
986-1989
```

It takes "986-1989" from the date "1986-1989".

My regex:

```
((?:\d{1}[-\/\.\s]|\+\d{2}[-\/\.\s]??|\d{2}[-\/\.\s]??|\d{3}[-\/\.\s]??|\d{4}[-\/\.\s]??)?(?:\d{3}[-\/\.\s]??\d{3}[-\/\.\s]??\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}))
```

Any suggestions on how to change this regex so that it doesn't consider the year?

Comment: Would you like to have a match in `Tel123-5678` / `Tel_123-5678` where numbers are glued to some letters/underscores? Can you use lookbehinds or do you target all possible JavaScript environments? If you are limited in regex feature choice, are you extracting or replacing?

Comment: it should just match with the telephone number. Tel123-5678 will be "123-5678". I am extracting. When i added the boundary \b to my regex other features weren't working for example there was a match for the number "123456-4343" which is incorrect.

Comment: I know that "just use word boundary" won't work here. So, can you use lookbehinds? I optimized your pattern a bit and added lookarounds, please see `/(?<!\w)(?:\d[-\/.\s]|\+\d{2}[-\/.\s]?|\d{2,4}[-\/.\s]?)?(?:\d{3}[-\/.\s]?\d{3}[-\/.\s]?\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4}|\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4})(?!\d)/g` [here](https://regex101.com/r/QFTATD/1).

Comment: What is the programming language? Python and JavaScript solutions might differ, and `grep` solution might also be different from the other two - all three use different regex engines.

Comment: i am using python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you can use lookarounds, so you can use a pattern that only matches your phone numbers if there are no digits on both ends of the potential match.

```
re.findall(r'(?<!\d)(?:\d[-/.\s]|\+\d{2}[-/.\s]?|\d{2,4}[-/.\s]?)?(?:\d{3}[-/.\s]?\d{3}[-/.\s]?\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4}|\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4})(?!\d)', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QFTATD/3).

Note you do not need to escape forward backslash in a Python regex string since `/` is not any special regex metacharacter.

Note also the `(?<!\d)` lookbehind and `(?!\d)` lookahead that fail the match if there is a digit before or after the pattern respectively.

I suggest replacing `??` with `?` in your regex because the lazy pattern does not have any advantage here.

The `\d{2}[-\/\.\s]??|\d{3}[-\/\.\s]??|\d{4}[-\/\.\s]??` part only differs in the amount of digits matched, so I shortened it to `\d{2,4}[-/.\s]?`.

The `.` char inside a character class needs no escaping as it only denotes a literal dot char there (`[.]` = `\.` in regex)